# Display the component view or layout into a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, custom-module, mvc

I've built my own component `com_mycomp` and in the component there is form in a `layout` and the path to this layout is:
`com_mycomp/site/layouts/subscription/form.php`

so I want to show this layout (form) in an article so I need to build a module to do the job for me, right?

**my Question**:

- can I load the layout in the module?
- I've also tried to build a `view` to show the layout but I also can't load the `view` in the `module`, any thoughts?

***P.S. I don't want to use an external module or plugin***

Comment: You can create a module and add it to an article using the editor. You can use the same field as you used in the layout and use the same table (if you use database).

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães (this is not a gumpy message) Your comment does not seek clarification of question details -- it is providing a possible resolution.  Comments should not attempt to provide a resolution.  To post resolving advice, please post an answer.  If you are not confident about your resolving advice, please phrase your comment to ask something of the OP -- this is a minor re-wording of your comment. e.g. "Do you know how to add a module into an article? Have you seen this? https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F"  Be careful to ask (not tell) in comments.

Comment: @Trolli So you don't want this?  https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/loadposition-loadmodule/

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry if my question was not clear, I know how to load module in an article. I want to know to load a layout component or a view in the  module :)

Comment: @TrolliFlame Welcome to JSE just the same.  Please take our [tour] to begin to familiarise yourself with our community.

Comment: You are right @mickmackusa. So comments are for seeking clarifications, however, I am also afraid of getting downvoted for not meeting their expectations. By the way, You are my Tutor, whatever you say I don't take as an offense but as a valuable lesson. Thank you.

Comment: I saw the downvote on your other answer -- it is not very common that downvotes happen here.  Please be careful about the advice that you give and support your posts with references to credible references and documentation -- these things should help to protect you from DVs.  I love your enthusiasm and eagerness to engage here.  I will continue to offer you and others guidance because it is part of my responsibilities and because I genuinely wish to help everyone.  My Joomla skills are not extensive, but we can all contribute in meaningful ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would **program a custom module** for this purpose.

In its **helper file** I would load the Model of your component to retrieve the items that you will display.

Check out a Joomla core module like /modules/**mod_articles_latest** to see how it re-uses Joomla's ContentModelArticles.

In the /tmpl/default.php I would put the html + php to display the data. As basis I would copy parts of the components html output.